# Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 not respecting valign in <td>

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, email-client, valign

I’ve set up a bare bones test here: https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/eypNVE82ae543QsSdfiYJlcLNqtcmvKz1ybIvJRlCPj2n/shared

The simple goal is to have the main text align to the top of its TD, and the CTA text align to the bottom of its TD. As you can see, this is happening in every client except the Outlooks noted above (ignore mobile for this question).
Note that we do not know if the CTA will be more than one line, so it's not possible to determine its height.

I’ll post the code snippet below.

Thanks!
Don

```
<table width=“640” border=“0” cellpadding=“0” cellspacing=“0”>
  <tr>
  <td valign=“top”>http://imgs.elainemedia.de/w4gu/f8451d426cd5373fde24a98fcf496945.jpg</td>
  <td valign=“top” bgcolor=”#000000”><table width=“100%” border=“0” cellspacing=“0” cellpadding=“0”>
      <tr>
      <td rowspan=“2” valign=“top”>http://imgs.elaine-asp.de/w4gu/1fce9767d9699082bfea5b0c475aece5.gif</td>
      <td valign=“top”>Buy a Pro’s Bike
        Ridden by the world’s finest, now available to you. With our Original Pro Bikes it’s easier than ever to own a unique piece of cycling history.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td valign=“bottom” style=“color:#ffffff;”>CTA GOES HERE</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Valign does not work because your inner table height does not scale up to the parent td height.

The problem you have, that there is no sure way to control the height of your inner `table` to fit outer table (besides fixed height on `td`'s in both tables). I'm assuming you are trying to set height of the inner table by using invisible spacer gif image, but from your snippet I can't deduce if you have set height of the `img` tag.

Example:

```
<img src="http://imgs.elaine-asp.de/w4gu/1fce9767d9699082bfea5b0c475aece5.gif" 
     height="260" width="1" style="display: block; border: none;" alt="" />
```

Note: if the example above doesn't work, try changing spacer gif original image size from 1x1 to 10x10 pixels. Below is a quote from [this article explaining spacer gifs in Outlook](http://www.murraymoffatt.com/software-problem-0014.html):

> The fix is surprisingly easy and doesn't require any changes to the message markup. Instead just change the spacer GIF so that it is 10 x 10 pixels instead of 1 x 1. I think Outlook is maybe looking out for images that are 1 x 1 and treating them differently, maybe because they are often used as web beacons. (...) Of course you can still set the HEIGHT and WIDTH of the spacer GIFs to a size smaller than 10 x 10, so it's still possible to have them set to 1 x 1 and they'll still work as before.

Another solution is to remove inner table completely, and rebuild outer one as follows:

```
<table align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
       width="640" style="width: 640px; background-color: #000000;">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" rowspan="2">
      <img src="http://imgs.elainemedia.de/w4gu/f8451d426cd5373fde24a98fcf496945.jpg" 
           width="460" height="280" style="display: block; border: none;" alt="">
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="color: #ffffff;">
      Buy a Pro’s Bike<br>
      Ridden by the world’s finest, now available to you. 
      With our Original Pro Bikes it’s easier than ever to own 
      a unique piece of cycling history.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="color: #ffffff;">
      <!-- note you can go any align/valign combination here -->
      CTA GOES HERE
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See how the two compare. I have added borders to illustrate how the `td`'s and `tables` stacks against each other.
https://jsfiddle.net/jtquaja1/2/

Answer (score 0):

Spacer images are a nice and simple solution, but can cause issues due to things like Outlook ignoring html image re-sizing, Outlooks different rendering of [image size based on DPI](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013) as well as issues with image blocking or image-to-text ratio ([importance is up for argument currently](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/does_text_to_image_ratio_affect_deliverability))

The most comprehensive cross email client alternative, although time consuming and complex, is to create a row above and below each and using height (with mso-line-height-rule for small rows in Outlook) to make each table the same size and the content centered.

sample: `<tr><td height="10" style="font-size:10px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>content goes here</td></tr> <tr><td height="10" style="font-size:10px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>`

This can be accomplished using padding as well on the TD, instead of new rows. Some consider this to not be a comprehensive solution due to some mail clients may not render the padding correctly. I personally use the padding method as it is more efficient and more controllable for responsive design and have not found any issues in any email clients or browser.

sample: `<tr><td style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">content goes here</td></tr>`

Whatever you choose, my best advice is to test, test, test and test some more.